# phonegap addEventListener trigger slowly for 2nd time execution

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

```
<script>
function onbattery() {
window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
document.getElementById('log1').innerHTML+="clicked";       
}

function onBatteryStatus(info) {

document.getElementById('log2').innerHTML+="get";
document.getElementById('getbatstatus').innerHTML+="Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: "     + info.isPlugged;
}
</script>

<p id="log1">will display log1</p>
<p id="log2">will display log2</p>
<p id="getbatstatus">will display battery status</p>
```

---

Above code will display current battery status. On 1st click it showing very fast. But when i want to run it again..it will execute very slowly... why is this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is the batterystatus event only occurs when the battery status changes (power level increases, decreases or you plug your device in)

The first time you call onbattery, it gives the current status but then it waits for the system to raise the batterystatus event (could be a few minutes before change if you have a string battery)

Comment: make sense !. Then should I do remove the event listener, in order to execute the eventlistener again?

Comment: No, if you always want to have the current battery status level, keep the event listener running hut save the value to a global variable.   Then read that value when you do your click

Comment: i tried that. But with no success. I think i want to save the current battery status to localstorage, then read it up again whenever  i want to read the current battery status, before the battery increase or decrease its percentage from last read.